# Why does my kamado ceramic grill fall out of it's stand when I open it?

Tags: equipment, grilling, barbecue

I just got a Large Big Green Egg with a nest. When I was at the store, they asked if I wanted one already put together, so I said yes. They gave me a nest that had a medium sitting in it.

Now, when I put my large in it, it fits fine; however, when I open it, if I push on it a little, it starts to slip out. It looks as if I don't save it, it will fall completely out.

[image: Big Green Egg]

The nest has little rubber protectors on each bar holding the egg. It appears that as it starts to slip, these protectors are slipping off, which very well may be what is causing this.

My question is, is it normal to have these rubber protectors on the 4 middle bars that hold the egg in place?  I'm not sure if the store maybe added these just because they had a medium egg sitting inside the nest which was a few inches too small (the bars did not touch it).

It seems that removing them might solve this issue; however, I by no means want to do this if it will scratch up the egg. Since it was already put together, I don't know if they were supposed to be there in normal use or not.

Comment: This post makes no sense to me.

Comment: I am not sure what makes no sense to you.  If you have a BGE Nest you will notice the egg is held in by four bars.  Do these four bars have a slid on/off rubber cover on their tips in order to protect the egg.  If a standard BGE Nest does not have these, then they were added on by the company I bought it from simply to protect the egg from scratching.  If this is the case, this is likely why my egg is falling out backwards when I open it.

While the edit of my title by another user made it a tad bit misleading, it is still pretty self-explainable.

Comment: Perhaps add a link to the thing that you're describing so that people understand what it is and how it relates to cooking, and isn't just a complete non sequitor?

Comment: Big green egg is a brand of kettle style BBQ. The nest is the stand. AFAIK BGE is just another marketing invention, designed to open you wallet. It looks like it should fail as per OP question. What's wrong with a pile of wood, some stones, and a metal grill?

Comment: The Big Green Egg is the name of a popular charcoal bbq here in North America. This is possibly a somewhat localized question, hence the confusion. http://biggreenegg.ca/ I think your question is fine, but it probably would help to have a bit of background and the link in there....

Comment: The question originally had "big green egg:" at the beginning of the title since if you don't know what one is you surely do not have one to answer the question. The question is specific to people who knows and uses bge so explaining what the product is would be sort of pointless. Per the FAQ it says to post on this stack exchange with questions on equipment, which the bge is.  Seems ill have to wait till tomorrow though to call them because by now I'm surely not setting it up this late. I will post the correct answer none the less tomorrow for others with this issue.

Comment: Anthony, you don't always get answers within a few hours, especially not when you're asking about equipment that most people don't have. And not everyone knows what a big green egg is, so I don't think you should be too surprised by the reaction when you posted a question without context. Tacking "kettle BBQ" on isn't a big change, and it makes the question understandable, which is good for everyone (including you, for the sake of getting answers).

Comment: Also sorry about the Confusion but that was likely added by others editing my detailed post to a very specific issue with more broad sentences, such as my original subject made it extremely clear it was for big green egg users only. Sadly I have no control over others editing my question that I am aware of.

Comment: Jet: that is fine it was worth asking here in case someone did.  However it was a question for a very specific product and specific accessory, so I would say changing that more so made the question confusing. None the less ill post the answer tomorrow once I talk to the store.  Have a great night.

Comment: Are the nests one size fits all? The image posted seems to have differently-sized nests for differently-sized kettles. You said you bought a large and the one they gave you had a medium on it. Could there be a size mismatch?

Comment: Yam: They said that they just had the medium egg sitting it in but it was a large.  I believe that is the case because the large fits perfectly with no room and the medium wasn't even touching the nest sides.  However it definitely was the rubber stoppers. they were not supposed to be there.  THanks all!

Comment: Yam: I also confirmed it was via BGE tech support. I posted this last night after they were closed, as calling them was my first attempt at solving the issue.  I wrote the answer below and will mark it tomorrow once I am allowed to.  Thanks again all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rubber stoppers I have are in fact part of the nest.  After speaking with a rep, they are there to actually help stop the issue I am having.  However, mine feel like they are taking away traction because they easily slip on and off, as apposed to add to it, so they are sending me a new set.  It is possible that they are stretched, since it is a floor model. They are also very dusty inside, so cleaning them out would also probably help the traction, however I am going to wait till I receive a new set.

For the time being, having the stoppers off makes it so it won't fall out.  It still tips if I physically push with the lid a bit, however it no longer feels like it will fall out.  Especially once I added all the parts inside to help weigh it down.

Hope this helps anyone else who has a similar issue.

Comment: Oh good, that was going to be my next guess: "floor model" and "pre-assembled" often equate to "damaged"

Comment: Yeh I wasn't to found of it when they asked if i wanted them to assemble it but then said take the floor model, however with the amazing warranty of the big green egg, I figured if something is wrong I can always get it fixed and skip all the work of putting it together.  Tech support was awesome.

Answer (score 5):

The nest for the Egg should fit snugly in the grill, and you should never get the sense that it is tipping or sliding when opening the lid. If this is the case, then either the nest was not properly assembled, or it is not the correct nest for your grill.

You should contact Big Green Egg corporate with your issue. It may behoove you to take pictures, and offer to e-mail them to the rep that is assigned to your issue. You should also mention the name of the distributor, as I am sure the manufacturer would want to know if their product and brand are being represented poorly.

That will probably bring resolution to your problem. You can also bring your issue to their online community: http://eggheadforum.com/

Comment: The forum users need to be approved before they can post.  Tried that first than came here in case someone else had this issue and could possibly help last night.  Did just speak with customer service since they are now open and the stoppers should be there.  They however may be streched so hes sending new ones.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the EGG is not seated all the way down on the nest bottom or you do not have the firebox/frire ring in the grill which adds needed weight. If that does not help.

Call 770.938.9394 BGE Customer Service or Email photo to retail@biggreenegg.com

EGGspert.

Comment: The egg was sitting in all the way and I had the parts in there. The problem was that the stoppers I had were hindering, not adding to the traction of keeping the egg locked in.  Probably because they were streched out and also dirty inside.  It's was like having basketball sneakers that are made to stop quickly, but then putting tons of dirt on the bottom. It just makes it worse.  As for tech, they were closed when I posted this.  That was my first option I tried.  Thanks though for the feedback! My first chicken breast turned out awesome, and brining a turkey now for the AM =)